# laser-crisp picture -- what does "laser-crisp" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [Running Linux, 5th Edition by Matthias Kalle Dalheimer and Matt Welsh (2006)](http://www.bokus.com/bok/9780596007607/running-linux-5th-edition/)

Example:

> When one wants Internet access enough, any wire will do. There are intensive experiments to use even the electricity grid to deliver Internet access. So it’s not surprising that companies that built their business plans on delivering **laser-crisp pictures** of sporting events (the cable TV firms) would realize they could devote one of their channels to a local area network carrying digital data—hence the advent of cable Internet access.

What exactly does "laser-crisp" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the the picture is very, very clear and the outlines of the objects in the picture are very crisp and clean, as a laser line is crisp and clean.

The clarity of a televised picture increases as the **resolution** increases.  4k pictures are clearer than HD, and 8K are even more clear.

Your article snippet talks about how to deliver high resolution transmissions since the high resolutions require higher bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

**laser crisp** is a slight misquote of a widely used expression **laser sharp**: see this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laser%20sharp%2Claser%20crisp&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claser%20sharp%3B%2Cc0).

Laser light is coherent: it does not spread or diffuse to the same extent as other light sources. In 1962, scientists pointed a laser at the moon to measure the earth-to-moon distance accurately: the spot on the moon's surface (385,000km away) was less than 7km across. Lasers are therefore synonymous with precision, especially between light and dark areas.

A [sharp](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sharp) image is one where the boundary between two different colours in the image is very precise: there is a sharp contrast between the two colours. 
Likewise, a [crisp](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crisp) image is very clear.